# How to find Project details along with number of working employees?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Project_details` (Pid, Pname, Location) and `Emp_details` (Eid, Ename, Address, Pid, salary)

[image]

Query is to get:

1. How to find project details along with the number of employees working with them
2. How do we find the details of employee with maximum salary.

For the first query, I can get Pid with number of working employees with them as

```
Select Pid, count(Eid) as [no of employees] 
from Emp_details 
group by(Eid) 
order by(count(Eid)) desc;
```

For second query this is Okay:

```
Select * 
from Emp_details 
where salary = (Select max(salary) from Emp_details);
```

But what if two employees have the same salary, in that case how do we make sure to get details of both employees?

Comment: Since the max salary will be one only so you can define based on the rownumber or take the first of that

Answer (score 0):

answer your second question first, your query already returns all the employees with highest salary

for the first question you can do, you can join two tables and group it by project id and then calculate number of employees in each project

```
select p.id, p.name , p.location , count(*) as [no of employees] 
from project p
join Emp_details e
 on e.pid = p.id
group by p.id, p.name , p.location
```